# Facebook PHP SDK SSL ERROR

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a SSL issue when I use the Facebook PHP SDK.
I got this error message:

> ERROR SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I already got some sugestion from other posts and include some params to my curl.
But I still getting the error:

The code of mu curl is this:

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.1',
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
```

);

Some one knows how can I eliminate this error?

Best, Flavio

Answer (score -1):

Change the VERIFYHOST option to:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
```

This'll disable the verification process.

Comment: Sorry Marc, but the problem still happen, any other idea?

Comment: verifypeer=false should disable the CA check. for some reason it's not doing so on your code. So... no idea.

Comment: this is a **BAD** suggestion! and can lead to a dangerous security threats!

Comment: @ifaour: no worse than what SSL already does with 6 kajillion low-quality badly-secured lowest-bid CAs are already causing with fake google/amazon/mozilla certs floating around.